# Airflow DAG breaks with JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

So my DAG starts like given below:

```
import airflow
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

default_args = {
"owner": "scheduled_queries",
"depends_on_past": False,
"start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
"email": Variable.get("email"),
"email_on_failure": True,
"email_on_retry": True,
"retries": 0,
"retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('scheduled_queries',
schedule_interval=None, #'0 0 * * *',
#template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
default_args=default_args
)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
"
Broken DAG (dags/testdag.py):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1 (char 263)
"
```

Have got no idea on why this is happening. Because the same DAG works well in other environments like UAT.
Kindly guide me with the issue and solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, we had something similar in one of our environments and the issue was traced to invalid JSON (a typo) in one of our Variables. As in the global Airflow Variables tab in the UI.